# С++. Заполнить массив единицами и тройками на главной диагонали

Tags: c++, массивы

Вот код :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));    // инициализация функции rand значением функции time
    const int n = 5;  // количество строк
    const int m = 5; // количество столбцов
    int** data = new int*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        data[i] = new int[m];
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            data[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    /*Начало вашего кода*/
    //TODO: Пишите код тут
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        data[i] = new int[m];
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if (i == j) {
                data[i][j] = 1;
            } else {
                data[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    /*Конец вашего кода*/
    /*Памятка! Если вы стёрли строки доступные для редактирования - нажмите F5*/


    cout << endl;
    cout << "output array:";
    cout << endl;
    cout << "{";
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "{";
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if (j > 0)
                cout << ", ";
            cout << data[i][j];
        }
        cout << "}";
        if (i != (n - 1))
            cout << ",";
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "}";
    delete[] data;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

единицы я вывел на главной диагонали, не пойму как между ними и 3 вставить

Comment: Ну сами посудите, если i=j то элемент равен 1, если, к примеру, индексы четные присвойте значение 3

Comment: так а как реализовать это кодом?

Answer (score 2):

```
for  (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
          data[i][i] = (i & 1) ? 3 : 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(i == j && i % 2 == 0) data[i][i] = 1;
else if( i == j) data[i][i] = 3;
```